# How to display data on .ascx file using C# via calling property

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline, ascx

For some reason, when I run the page, no value is sent back from the server?

I have the following property:

```
public bool GetTest
{
    get 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I have the following inline C# code on the .ascx file which is surrounded by `<h3>` tags.

```
<h3>
   <%this.GetTest.ToString();%>
</h3>
```

I build the project, there are no errors, and the when I run the page on the browser, the expected value is not appearing.

Any ideas? I am pretty sure there is a school boy error here somewhere but I can't spot it.

Comment: Please fix ascx code, it's empty now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<%= this.GetTest.ToString() %>` in your `<h3>` tag

Comment: Actually, I didnt really need that code above, it was example of the problem I was getting. I used the <%= where my problem was but it returned an error but in the example above it did work, so I then remembered this <%# which worked with my problem. Would you happen to what the difference is?

Comment: Take a look at this article, there are inline expressions described in details: https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/976112